# Which is the most reliable way to use a API. integrating/downloading an SDK to your application, or using the URL-HTTP-GET method

Tags: ios, api, sdk

I want to know which is the best and most reliable method. i have looked on here for an answer but didn't come across any.

I Want to use multiple API'S in my project so please keep that in mind when answering. Any advice about the best way of doing this and most reliable method will really be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Isit possible to download multiple SDK's into an iOS application through Xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Pros of SDK:

- Can be used offline
- Most SDKs are small in file size
- All of the functioning code is visible to you, the SDK developer can't keep many secrets

### Cons of SDK:

- Larger binary
- More clutter in your Xcode project

### Pros of API:

- Smaller binary
- Less 3rd party frameworks cluttering your Xcode project

### Cons of API:

- Can't be used offline
- Tends to be a blackbox
- App will need to be updated every time the API is updated

In terms of reliability, the SDK will always be functional assuming

1. It worked in the first place
2. It doesn't rely on an API in the background

Comment: Remember to mark it as the current answer if it helped.

Comment: What about if i wanted to add multiple sdk's is that possible & will it still be reliable... loading time, bugs, ECT.

Comment: Loading time will go up, and bugs are dependent on the quality of the SDKs. But overall, adding multiple SDKs tends to be safe.

Comment: So in my situation would you use multiple api's or install multiple SDK's. Only been coding for a couple months and not sure which route to take, Using SDK's seems more reliable but Will the loading time be a problem(really long) for 3 SDK's in my project?

Comment: Usually adding SDKs to your project adds mere milliseconds to your load time, it's nothing to worry about until you see multiple second app launch times. I would definitely use multiple SDKs assuming they were all stable.

Comment: An SDK can be binary only meaning that there is no code visible and the SDK developer can keep lots of secrets.

Comment: How would i know which SDK's are stable??

Comment: Thanks for the help people!!

Comment: @maddy I recommend against those unless they're from a trusted source. P-Junior: Check if the SDK has a SO tag, if it does, check out if the majority of answers claim it's a bug. If the SDK has a GitHub, or any other repository management system, check the Issues section or Pull Requests, it's pretty easy to spot if an SDK is unstable.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate SDK using Cocoapods library.CocoaPods is a ruby gem that downloads all the third party libraries that you want for your project.

Getting a specific version of a pod is done by specifying the version number, and CocoaPods downloads that specific version for you saving you from searching through commits for it.

With CocoaPods, updating your dependancies is easily done with the pod update command.

CocoaPods also provides a central place where third party libraries can be found. This improves discoverability of open source libraries that you can use in your projects. You can use the search engine at cocoapods.org to search for pods.